Trying to publish a trimmed ASP.NET Core MVC application, nonsense error involving missing type hashset
I'm trying to publish an ASP.NET Core MVC application with trimmed runtime. (The application itself cannot be trimmed because of reflection-accessed models; as is typical of ASP.NET Core MVC; however my understanding is this should not block the creation of a trimmed single file executable - but all types in my own assembly are considered rooted).
However immediately on activating trim with
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
<IsTrimmable>false</IsTrimmable>

I get the following incomprehensible error:

obj/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.SourceGeneration/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.SourceGeneration.ConfigurationBindingGenerator/BindingExtensions.g.cs(130,70):
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HashSet<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This file doesn't exist in the directory tree so I cannot open it to inspect it.

.net 9 I'm assuming?

@CarterCanedy: .net 9 is not released; therefore .net 8 currently

Interesting. Sounds like a good issue to report in the asp.net core repo

@CarterCanedy: It does; but it's not bisecting yet and I have literally nothing to go on to find the offending file. It's not the model that contains HashSet.

I was never able to bisect the problem; however the problem can be cleared by one line in the project file.
    <EnableConfigurationBindingGenerator>false</EnableConfigurationBindingGenerator>

I don't get it. It's trying to generate some code for something that looks close enough to something that can go into an IConfiguration, and the code generator is spitting out nonsense.
However for the next guy coming past; a trimmed MVC binary does not work. I made a little more progress before running into an insurmountable problem. After adding:
  <ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" />
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="my application assembly" />
  </ItemGroup>

The application dies with
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ConsolidatedAssemblyApplicationPartFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

This is not cannot find the type; this is cannot load it. The class constructor threw an exception; and due to the construction of .NET we don't find out what it was. Progress stops here.
